# Как сделать цифры "счётчик" у элемента li

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, li

У меня не получается добавить цифры к элементу li, как на макете

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 1px;
}

.side-news-header-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.side-news-header-title::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 66px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #e1d9bd;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}

.side-themes {
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.theme {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.themes {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-themes">
  <div class="side-news-header">
    <h3 class="side-news-header-title">Темы</h3>
  </div>

  <ul class="themes">
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Красота</a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Здоровье</a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Образ жизни</a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Музыка</a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Спорт</a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Йога</a></li>
    <hr>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать тег `sup` например:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  height: 1px;
}

.side-news-header-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.side-news-header-title::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 66px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #e1d9bd;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}

.side-themes {
  margin-top: 55px;
}

.theme {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.themes {
  display: block;
}

sup {
  color: #e1d9bd;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-themes">
  <div class="side-news-header">
    <h3 class="side-news-header-title">Темы</h3>
  </div>

  <ul class="themes">
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Красота <sup>12</sup></a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Здоровье <sup>4</sup></a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Образ жизни <sup>145</sup></a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Музыка <sup>28</sup></a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Спорт <sup>62</sup></a></li>
    <hr>
    <li><a class="theme" href="#">Йога <sup>8</sup></a></li>
    <hr>
  </ul>
</div>
```